# How do I enable anonymous authentication for a specific IP subnet in IIS7 while maintaining basic authentication for every other IP subnet?

Tags: authentication, web-config, iis-7.5, basic-authentication

I've stumbled across an issue with IIS7; apparently it is not possible to limit "anonymous authentication" to a certain range of IP addresses, i.e. a subnet, at least not in the GUI for a certain folder within a website:

- 10.0.0.0/24: anonymous access to "/lan_ok_outside_basiconly"
- Every other IP: Basic Auth to "/lan_ok_outside_basiconly"

The application within the folder does not need user credentials, it just needs to verify that the access is to be granted either by verifying that the client is in a specific internal LAN or by basic auth credentials from everyone else.

Is there any way to achieve this in IIS7.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

We can provide the authentication in sitelevel and application context level based on our requirement.

For example assume a website

www.example.com exists in your IIS

you can specify the authentication by selecting this site -> authentication tab -> anonymus or windows or both

Same as like above if you have contexts(for example) like

www.example.com/ex1,    www.example.com/ex2,    www.example.com/ex3

then you can select any context and you can specify the Authentication as per your requirement.

For more details check the below link for some reference

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication